# Dronekit-Python Error with Raspberrypi4-Ubuntu20.04 "dronekit.APIException"

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.8, raspberry-pi4, dronekit

I'm trying to run the script by python2-3 (alias).
This is for drone's flight so I'm using dronekit.
But I got this error as below.
Please help me to solve this error.

- Ubuntu20.04
- Raspberrypi 4 Board
- Dronekit 2.9.2
- Python2.7 & Python3.8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp2Fb.jpg)

Comment: Please don't take screenshots of your code and errors. Instead you should include them in your question as text. That way it is easier for people to work with it. Please read [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal output that you posted, there is a Timeout exception at the line which reads `vehicle = connect('/dev/ttyAMA0', baud=921600, wait_ready=True)` . More details about your setup would be useful, but I'm going to assume you are using a serial radio to communicate with your drone. If that's true, some troubleshooting steps may be:

- Make sure the radio is being mounted to /dev/ttyAMA0.
- Make sure the baud rate for the radio is 921600. If it's something different, pass this value in as the baud parameter in `connect`.

When asking questions, it's best to give as much detail as possible, and, as the above commenter said, please include code as text instead of linking to screenshots.